# Difference between sendRedirect(test.jsp) and sendRedirect(/test.jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, url, redirect, servlets

I want to pay attention to `/` used in redirect.

> Forward slash at the beginning means "relative to the root of this web
> container - Head First JSP and Servlets

I thought I understand it, until I tried it out. I will put super simple code for demonstration:

Starts with index.html:

```
<html><body>
    <form action="GenericServlet" method="POST">
        Enter name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <button>Submit name</button>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Then it goes to GenericServlet.class:

```
@WebServlet("/GenericServlet")
public class GenericServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        resp.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
        
    }
}
```

, which redirects to test.jsp:

```
<html><body>
hellooooo
</body></html>
```

After I run it, I get `hellooo` message. But once I change redirect to `/test.jsp` instead of `test.jsp`, I get **not found error**.

I also noticed when I use redirect(test.jsp), I get this **http://localhost:8080/testProject/index.html**
.But, when I use redirect(/test.jsp), I get this: **http://localhost:8080/test.jsp**

If Head First told me that `/` stands for `root`, why am I not getting same URL as in first case? **Root = testProject**, right? Can anyone spot what am I saying wrongly?

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to example described at: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch04s27.html. From what I remember container is application which handles *your application*. In this case it is a server so "relative to the root of this web container" most likely means "relative to server address" which in your case is `http://localhost:8080`. Result from linked article seems to confirm it (notice that there is no `/myApp` before `/foo/stuff.html` in resulting URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root = testProject**? NO!

The root path is the doman part without any path,which is **http://localhost:8080** in you context.

For example, suppose the current request url is `http://localhost:8080/a/b`, if you call `resp.sendRedirect("c");`, the next request url is `http://localhost:8080/a/c`. If you call `resp.sendRedirect("/c");`, the next request url will be `http://localhost:8080/c`.